# Why am I getting list index errors?

Tags: python

My text file has 6 lines but everytime verify is run twice it always gets:

```
  File "verifier.py", line 34, in <module>
    verify(i)
  File "verifier.py", line 27, in verify
    real_account = account[acc_no]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

When I replace acc_no with just 2 it works fine, but when printing out acc_no I get 2 so I do not know why it is printing this error my code:

```
import random
import time
import json
import threading
import requests
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from colorama import init
from colorama import Fore, Back, Style
from datetime import datetime

init(autoreset=True)

config = json.load(open("config.json"))
times = int(config['amount'])
delay = int(config['verifier_delay'])
username = config['username']
password = config['password']
read_file = open("accounts.txt", "r")
acc_no=0

def verify(acc_no):
    account = read_file.readlines()
    real_account = account[acc_no]
    username = real_account[0:real_account.find(":")]
    password = real_account[real_account.find(":")+1:]
    print(username + password)
    print(acc_no)

for i in range (times):
    verify(i)

time.sleep(5)
```

Comment: Have you tried to use a debugger? What can you see there?

Answer (score 0):

You are reaching the point where `account` doesn't have a valid index for `acc_no`. Try catching the error and seeing what these values actually are:

```
try:
    real_account = account[acc_no]
except IndexError:
    print(acc_no, account)
```

I think you'll find that account is not what you think it is!

Comment: I did catch the errors and it prints out 1 when the text file has six lines @101

Answer (score 0):

The `readlines()` function reads all the lines from the current position to the end of the file. When you call `verify()` a second time, you're already at the end of the file, so there's nothing left to read.

You need to seek back to the beginning of the file first.

```
def verify(acc_no):
    read_file.seek(0)
    account = read_file.readlines()
    ...
```

But instead of reading the file repeatedly, you could just read it once and save that in a global variable. Then you can reuse that variable each time.

```
with open("accounts.txt", "r") as read_file:
    account = read_file.readlines()
```

Comment: If I add the with statement I get:

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
    verify(i)
    read_file.seek(0)
ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.

Comment: I don't see any `read_file.close()` in your code, I don't see how that could be happening.

Comment: You shouldn't use *both* of my solutions, pick one. Either read the file once and save it in a variable, or use `seek(0)` before reading the file each time.

Comment: I'm still getting index out of range with the with statement, I'm almost certain though this isn't an issue with opening the file or real_account = account[1] should return an index error

Comment: I think the file was maybe messed up I deleted the text file then remade it now the with statement works thanks

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be opening read_file once, and then trying to read its entire content with read_file.readlines() every time you enter the verify() function.

AFAIK, readlines reads the entire file, so it cannot work a second time without reopening the file. Am I missing something? 
[The docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files) say:

> If you want to read all the lines of a file in a list you can also use
>   list(f) or f.readlines()

Comment: so if I add the open file into the verify loop the problem should be fixed?

Comment: I'm almost certain it's something to do with acc_no as when I just do real_account = account[1] it works

Answer (score 0):

List will raise `IndexError` when you try to fetch positional value where position itself does not exist. So the problem would be either

1. File is empty
2. File is not empty but the `acc_no` you supply does not exists in the `account`
3. Exception raised if loop executes twice where `read_file.readlines()` will return `[]` an empty list.

Now coming to the solution here is mine.

```
import random
import time
import json
import threading
import requests
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from colorama import init
from colorama import Fore, Back, Style
from datetime import datetime

init(autoreset=True)

config = json.load(open("config.json"))
times = int(config['amount'])
delay = int(config['verifier_delay'])
username = config['username']
password = config['password']
read_file = open("accounts.txt", "r")
account = read_file.readlines()
acc_len = len(account)
acc_no=0

def verify(acc_no):
    if acc_no >= acc_len:
         print('Account number does not exist in file. ', acc_no)
         return
    real_account = account[acc_no]
    username = real_account[0:real_account.find(":")]
    password = real_account[real_account.find(":")+1:]
    print(username + password)
    print(acc_no)

for i in range(times):
    verify(i)

time.sleep(5)
```

Cheers!